# assign variable dynamicly to object properties

Tags: javascript, json, angular, google-maps

I want to assign a variable to an object property.

```
this.dir = {
  origin : {
     lat :36.7014631
    , lng: -118.7559974
  },
  destination: { lat: 36.7014631, lng: -118.7559974}
}
```

The above code works fine, but  what I need below does not work:

```
this.dir = {
  origin : {
     lat :this.la,
     lng: this.lo
  },
  destination: { lat: 36.7014631, lng: -118.7559974}
}
```

I need this to bind in HTML like this:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-direction *ngIf="dir" [origin]="dir.origin" [destination]="dir.destination"></agm-direction>
</agm-map>
```

Comment: <button type="button" (click)="getDirection()">Get</button>
 
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-direction *ngIf="dir" [origin]="dir.origin" [destination]="dir.destination"></agm-direction>
</agm-map>

Comment: This isn't JSON. You're not describing what's wrong, but I guess you're just not sure how `this` works in JS.

Comment: my proble is that i have a varible  name la i want to assignt it in the varible lat in the object orgin but it daesn't work. the error is

Comment: So if it's the variable `la` thats not working, then why are you not showing us anything about `la`? Where is that value set? How is it defined? What's the scope? We need details

Comment: You can't access variables using `this`, unless you're talking about global variables and `this` is the global object. There's lots of info online that explains how `this` works in JS. Can't say precisely what's wrong because you didn't give a complete demo.

Comment: InvalidValueError: in property origin: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number; and unknown property lat

Comment: @CrazyTrain I believe he's using angular. the this keyword works per defined scope.

Comment: the varible la contain the result of a response api to get the logitude i test it it work fine but when assihgn it to the lat is not work

Comment: Well your error is telling you the value is invalid, so, whats the value?

Comment: i want to assign la to the varible lat because lat its neccesari for bind it to htmk which give me the marker of the longitude giveen

Comment: the value is a numberr but when i assign lat to static number like this lat:534653 it work but lat:this.la not work , i test the la in the console is a number value

Comment: any idea how to make object dynamicly then convert it to json format object ??

Comment: JSON is javascript object notation. Its the same things as the object you're already defining. JSON simply creates a standard across platforms to reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-direction *ngIf="dir" [origin]="dir.origin" [destination]="dir.destination"></agm-direction>
</agm-map>
```

You are attempting to set `lat` to `[latitude]` yet, according to your provided code, you have not defined lat as its own variable.

You have the field:

```
this.dir = {
  origin : {
     lat :this.la, 
     lng: this.lo
  },
  destination: { lat: 36.7014631, lng: -118.7559974}
}
```

So, change your template to not access `lat`, because it isn't defined in your controller, but rather access `dir.origin.lat`:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="dir.origin.lat" [longitude]="dir.origin.lng">
  <agm-direction *ngIf="dir" [origin]="dir.origin" [destination]="dir.destination"></agm-direction>
</agm-map>
```

Or, since it looks like you have a lat & long field already do it like so:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="la" [longitude]="lo">
  <agm-direction *ngIf="dir" [origin]="dir.origin" [destination]="dir.destination"></agm-direction>
</agm-map>
```

Comment: still the same error i tested it now .... ilat and lng are defined in my component their type number .  i thinks can't pass la to lat i d'ont khnow why ??

Comment: i foloowed this tuto and tried to modifiy the value of latitude and longitude to my varible la and lo  https://www.npmjs.com/package/agm-direction